WP_Query->get_posts() take too long time to load data maybe 33 sec
on my WooCommerce website (I did test 3 themes xstore - flatsome - woodmart) when trying to browse product category page its take long time to load, I did use Query monitor to check my issue i found that

WP_Query->get_posts()
wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3357
WP_Query->query()
wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3852
WP->query_posts()
wp-includes/class-wp.php:696
WP->main()
wp-includes/class-wp.php:816
wp() wp-includes/functions.php:1336
Main Query

take time to load more than 33 sec
and this is the log at Query:
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS mVkV6_posts.ID

FROM mVkV6_posts

LEFT JOIN mVkV6_term_relationships

ON (mVkV6_posts.ID = mVkV6_term_relationships.object_id)

INNER JOIN mVkV6_postmeta

ON ( mVkV6_posts.ID = mVkV6_postmeta.post_id )

INNER JOIN mVkV6_postmeta AS mt1

ON ( mVkV6_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )

WHERE 1=1

AND ( mVkV6_posts.ID NOT IN (

SELECT object_id

FROM mVkV6_term_relationships

WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (7,9) )

AND mVkV6_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (366) )

AND ( ( mVkV6_postmeta.meta_key = '_price'

AND CAST(mVkV6_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) != '' )

OR ( mt1.meta_key = '_price'

AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) != '0' ) )

AND ((mVkV6_posts.post_type = 'product'

AND (mVkV6_posts.post_status = 'publish'

OR mVkV6_posts.post_status = 'wc-shipping'

OR mVkV6_posts.post_status = 'wc-shipped-status'

OR mVkV6_posts.post_status = 'private')))

GROUP BY mVkV6_posts.ID

ORDER BY mVkV6_posts.menu_order ASC, mVkV6_posts.post_title ASC

LIMIT 0, 12


without knowing what the query was that it was trying to load from the PHP side it'll be difficult to make a suggestion, however the SQL query suggests an extremely expensive query is being made ( post meta queries get very slow on larger sites, and NOT IN clauses are extremely slow and don't scale either ). Note though that questions about 3rd party plugins are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope, and it's expected that you'd share code to be debugged, open ended discussions don't fit the sites format

try installing Query Monitor and check queries log

@MahdiAkrami
this report from Query Monitor
